# Which is better for left-to-right layout: float or display:inline?

Tags: css, inline, css-float, html

I have some icons inside divs and needed to lay them out with a left-to-right structure instead of the default top-to-bottom layout that seems to come with divs. It's probably not news to most people who know CSS but I figured out (with [a little help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107670/why-do-my-icons-line-up-top-to-bottom-instead-of-flowing-left-to-right-in-a-div-l)) that I could cause the divs to layout left-to-right using either:

```
float: left/right
```

or

```
display:inline.
```

My question is - **is one preferable over the other**?

```
<div id="icons">

  <div id="divtxt" class="divicon">
    <img src="/icons/text.png" id="icontxt" class="icon"/>
  </div>

  <div id="divpdf" class="divicon">
    <img src="/icons/pdf.png" id="icondoc" class="icon"/>
  </div>

  <div id="divrtf" class="divicon">
    <img src="/icons/rtf.png" id="iconrtf" class="icon"/>
  </div>
</div>

  div#icons
  {
    width:200px;
    height: 100px;
  }

  div.divicon
  {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    border: 0 0 0 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set an explicit width/height on inline elements, so if they must be a specific size then you're stuck with floating them. Floating elements can cause various layout quirks, so inline is definitely preferred if you don't *have* to float things.

Here, you should be able to set the size on the images instead of the divs. Then you could change the divs to spans which would naturally expand to the size of the images inside. (A span is just the inline companion to div, no need to create divs and then force them to `display: inline`.)

Answer (score 2):

One is not preferable over the other; they do different things.  When something is displayed inline, content that overflows the current line wraps to the next line.  A float, on the other hand, keeps the div displayed in a rectangular block.  So depending on your specific situation, you may find both useful.

In your given example, float would probably work much better.