# li float vs display: inline

Tags: css, html-lists

Is there a best choice out of `float: left` or `display: inline` for aligning list items horizontally?

eg: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/simple-navigation-bar-with-css-and-xhtml/

Personally I dislike `float`, but that maybe more of an emotional thing rather than logical.

Comment: You mean aligning them on the *left*, correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702669/what-is-the-difference-between-floatleft-vs-displayinline-while-every-element and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107820/which-is-better-for-left-to-right-layout-float-or-displayinline - trying to find closer matches

Comment: I dislike giving list items a `display:inline`, because they were not designed for that. Just like giving table cells other display values. `float` is what I would go with.

Answer (score 15):

```
ul { list-style-type: none; overflow: hidden; width:200px; }
ul li { float:left; width: 100px; }
ul li a { display: block; padding: 10px; width:80px; }
ul li a:hover { background: black; }


<ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>
  <li><a href="httpt://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is what I prefer mostly because when you use `display:inline` you cannot set properties like width, padding (top and bottom), margin etc... which is an handicap for layout purposes.

**EDIT 2014**

It is also an option to use the `display: inline-block` property. One think to note is that once you make the list elements inline or inline-block, white-spaces will be taken into consideration. Hence, there will be unwanted spaces between elements.

```
ul { list-style-type: none; width: 300px; font-size: 0; }
ul li { display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1; margin-right: 10px; } 
/* The *display and zoom is a IE hack, though can't remember 
   now which one (guess it is IE7) */
ul li a { display: inline-block; padding: 10px; font-size: 13px; }
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7m7c/) here.

If you don't want to use the `font-size` property (for browser compatibility issues), you can also use html comments to get rid off whitespaces! Though I prefer the method above.

```
   <ul><!--
    --><li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="httpt://www.google.com">Google</a></li><!--
--></ul>
```

Comment: Setting width can be a handicap itself if the contents happens not to fit the width.

Answer (score 9):

What about

```
li {
       display:inline-block
};
```

You can then set properties like width, heigth, padding, margin, etc..

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed some rendering bugs when displaying LI's Inline in chrome. My LI border sometimes does not render with the proper horizontal padding.

In general though, I like Inline, it still gives you horizontal margining and padding and you can do a nice text-align: center; on the UL and use the UL for vertical spacing.

I tend to use float purely because an LI is a block element by default and should be treated that way in my opinion but there are clear use cases for both.

Answer (score 0):

It's personal preference.

From a CSS point, `Display:Inline` = `Float:Left(Right)`.
When it comes to making elements horizontal, like `<li>`.

The css rule Float is newer than Display.